# How to make an entire row of AG-Grid a link?

Tags: ag-grid

When right-clicking onto the ag-grid row, there is no `Open in a new tab`, since the row is not actually a link. Is there a way to make the entire row a link? so that right-click context menu can have the `Open in a new tab` option?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a cellRenderer:

```
   cellRenderer: () => {
        return `
           <a style="display:block; width:100%;height:100%"
           href="https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#cell-rendering"

              hello 
           </a>`;
      },
```

Now if you click on the cell it will have the option.

You will probably need to reuse this across all columns to enable this on the entire row.